IPv6 only hotspot using hostapd and dnsmasq
to test the IPv6 capability of our end devices, i need to set up a hotspot on a raspberry pi that only provides ipv6 adresses.
I followed this guide: https://partiallydisassembled.net/posts/pi-nat64.html
I verified, that i have an IPv6 Adress on my wlan0 interface:
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::da3a:ddff:fe91:634  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fec0::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x40<site>
        ether d8:3a:dd:91:06:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17  bytes 2780 (2.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42  bytes 6004 (6.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

And hostapd is set up correct and running. I try to connect with my phone to the access point and i get a message, that no connection is possible.
If i check the debug output of dnsmasq, i see, that my phone sends a RTR-SOLICIT message and the router sends RTR-ADVERTs, but then nothing happens.
dnsmasq-dhcp: RTR-ADVERT(wlan0) fec0::
dnsmasq-dhcp: RTR-SOLICIT(wlan0) 48:bc:e1:fb:2a:ba
dnsmasq-dhcp: RTR-ADVERT(wlan0) fec0::
dnsmasq-dhcp: RTR-ADVERT(wlan0) fec0::
dnsmasq-dhcp: RTR-ADVERT(wlan0) fec0::

If switch everyhing to IPv4, everything works fine, so i think the issue is with dnsmasq configuration. My configuration file looks like this:
interface=wlan0
bind-interfaces
domain-needed
bogus-priv
server=2001:4860:4860::6464
local=/pi64/
domain=pi64
dhcp-fqdn
enable-ra
dhcp-range=::,constructor:wlan0,slaac
dhcp-option=option6:dns-server,2001:4860:4860::6464
dhcp-authoritative


What are you expecting to happen, though? SLAAC has no leases and no 'REQUEST' phase like DHCP does, so there's nothing else that could show up.
